# PHP - How do I unset an array index by value inside that index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of objects ($response) that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CardNumber] => 5897853070424xxx
            [CardHolderName] => P Stoltz
            [CardHolderContactNumber] => 
            [CardHolderEmailAddress] => 
            [CardExpiryDate] => 2017-09-01T00:00:00
            [CardHolderTypeID] => 2
            [LastUsedDate] => 2017-05-25T00:00:00
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CardNumber] => 589785304326xxx
            [CardHolderName] => J Stoltz
            [CardHolderContactNumber] => 
            [CardHolderEmailAddress] => 
            [CardExpiryDate] => 2017-09-01T00:00:00
            [CardHolderTypeID] => 2
            [LastUsedDate] => 2017-05-25T00:00:00
        )

)
```

Now, I need to unset the entire object where CardNumber != '589785304326xxx'

I have tried this:

```
$cardnumber = '5897853070424xxx'; 
    foreach( $response as $res )
    {
        if($res->CardNumber != $cardnumber)
        {
            unset($res);
        }
    }
```

This does nothing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I would rather suggest an [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have tried will only unset the current object in the loop. You need to do the following:

```
foreach($response as $key => $res) {
    if($res->CardNumber != $cardnumber) {
        unset($response[$key], $res);
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: That `continue` is rather superfluous there.

Comment: Thank you @Ryan Hipkiss - that works brilliantly.  Will accept as soon as the timer allows me.

Comment: @deceze put it in just to be sure xD

Answer (score -1):

Use `unset()` inside the loop.

eg:

```
unset('key value', 'your array name');
```